# Aggregation Sum in Prolog

Tags: prolog, relational-database

I have a table in Prolog like this:

```
invoice(number, locality, value)

invoice(1, madrid, 100)
invoice(2, lisbon, 200)
invoice(3, london, 300)
invoice(4, madrid, 300)
invoice(5, lisbon, 200)
invoice(6, paris, 100)
```

How can I get the agreggate sum for locality?

The answer should be something like doing a pivot table in Excel..

Lisbon total:400
Madrid total: 400
Paris total: 100
London total: 300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just to avoid that occasional visitors think that verbose code is *necessary* to get such basic thing done, here is the library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) way:

```
?- aggregate(sum(Value), Number^invoice(Number,Locality,Value), Sum).
Locality = lisbon,
Sum = 400 ;
Locality = london,
Sum = 300 
...
```

that is, we have the choice about 'pivot' columns. To get the full result, wrap into another aggregate:

```
?- aggregate(set(Locality=Sum), aggregate(sum(Value), Number^invoice(Number,Locality,Value), Sum), All).
All = [lisbon=400, london=300, madrid=400, paris=100].
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to make Town-Value pairs, group them by town, and calculate the sums for towns:

```
aggregate_sum_by_town(Result) :-
    findall(T-V, invoice(_, T, V), TVs),
    keysort(TVs, Ps),
    group_pairs_by_key(Ps, G),
    pairs_keys_values(G, Ks, Vs),
    maplist(sumlist, Vs, Ss),
    pairs_keys_values(Result, Ks, Ss).

?- aggregate_sum_by_town(Result).
Result = [lisbon-400, london-300, madrid-400, paris-100].
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods. 
The following programs are one of them.

```
/* agreggate_sum. */

agreggate_sum :-
        sum_calc( Data_list ),

        write( 'locality, total' ), nl,

        write_data( Data_list ).


sum_calc( Data_list ) :-
        findall( (Locality, Value), invoice(_, Locality, Value ), Invoice_list ),
        data_reduction( Invoice_list, [], Data_list ).


data_reduction( [], Data_list, Data_list ) :- !.

data_reduction( [(Locality, Value) | Result], Tmp_list, Data_list ) :-
        data_reduction2( Tmp_list, Locality, Value, Tmp_list2  ),
        data_reduction( Result, Tmp_list2, Data_list ).


data_reduction2( [], Locality, Value, [(Locality, Value)] ) :- !.

data_reduction2( [(Locality, Total_Value) | Result], Locality, Value, [(Locality, Total_Value2) | Result] ) :-
        !,
        Total_Value2 is Total_Value + Value.

data_reduction2( [(Locality2, Total_Value) | Result], Locality, Value, [(Locality2, Total_Value) | Result2] ) :-
        data_reduction2( Result, Locality, Value, Result2 ).


write_data( [] ) :- !.

write_data( [(Locality, Total_Value) | Result] ) :-
        write( Locality ), write( ', ' ), write( Total_Value ), nl,
        write_data( Result ).


invoice(1, madrid, 100).
invoice(2, lisbon, 200).
invoice(3, london, 300).
invoice(4, madrid, 300).
invoice(5, lisbon, 200).
invoice(6, paris, 100).
```

Result

```
9 ?- agreggate_sum.

locality, total

madrid, 400

lisbon, 400

london, 300

paris, 100
```

Comment: too much cuts ! actually, OP could get the impression they are necessary, while are not...